# Acknowledging a message from AMQP in Camel

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, apache-camel, amqp

Currently I'm using bluelock's camel-spring-amqp component for my application.

What I want to achieve is:

- Pull a message from RabbitMQ server.
- Persist it to a database on successful processing / Send it to another "Error" queue on Exception
- Tell the original queue that it is now safe to remove the message from the queue.

As of this writing, I'm able to pull from rabbit and persist to database using camel routes. What I don't really know how to do is acknowledge that my processing is done to the original queue. Here is my current route:

```
from("spring-amqp:EXCHANGE:queuename?autodelete=false&durable=true&type=direct&routingKey=")
            .bean(Transform.class, "transform(byte[])")
            .to("jpa:com.my.company.models.MyModel?entityType=java.util.ArrayList")
```

I realize I can set the acknowledgmentMode to NONE. But I don't know how to "manually" acknowledge once I have persisted my message.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I've suggested an answer to a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24804448/camel-raabitmq-acknowledgement/25935120#25935120 hope it helps.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Were you able to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm new in Camel but I know a thing or two about RabbitMQ.
With `RabbitMQConsumer` the message is acknowledged if the `processor` doesn't throw any exception (line 133 at [RabbitMQConsumer source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.camel/camel-rabbitmq/2.12.2/org/apache/camel/component/rabbitmq/RabbitMQConsumer.java/#128)).
So I suppose if you let your processor propagate the exception, the message won't be acknowledged. I haven't used spring-amqp but I guess it should have a similar behaviour.