# Camel RaabitMQ Acknowledgement

Tags: apache-camel, rabbitmq

I am using Camel for my messaging application. In my use case I have a producer (which is RabbitMQ here), and the Consumer is a bean.

```
from("rabbitmq://127.0.0.1:5672/exDemo?queue=testQueue&username=guest&password=guest&autoAck=false&durable=true&exchangeType=direct&autoDelete=false")
                .throttle(100).timePeriodMillis(10000)
                .process(new Processor() {                              
                        @Override
                        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                            MyCustomConsumer.consume(exchange.getIn().getBody())
                        }
                    });
```

Apparently, when autoAck is false, acknowledgement is sent when the process() execution is finished (please correct me if I am wrong here)

Now I don't want to acknowledge when the process() execution is finished, I want to do it at a later stage. I have a `BlockingQueue` in my MyCustomConsumer where consume() is putting messages, and MyCustomConsumer has different mechanism to process them. I want to acknowledge message only when MyCustomConsumer finishes processing messages from `BlockingQueue`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Putting a `BlockingQueue` after a RabbitMQ consumer might be a bad idea. If the route from the consumer to the `BlockingQueue` is lightweight compared to the consumer behind it, messages will be consumed quickly from RabbitMQ until the queue is full. Your messages are stored in memory, so if your process dies, they are lost. I also observed the RabbitMQ consumer stalling after a block from a `BlockingQueue`. Even after the consumer from the `BlockingQueue` finished processing all messages, the remaining messages from RabbitMQ were not consumed until the Camel context was restarted.

Comment: @StijnVanBael: Agreed on the point that when process dies, messages are lost. However no need to restart camel context for processing remaining messages; route will keep delivering messages to BlockingQueue.

Comment: That's what I thought as well. But practice proved otherwise. I've observed network traffic. When the queue blocks, the Camel consumer tells the broker to hold. But it never tells the broker to resume sending.

Comment: Didn't happen for us. May be because of our use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider to use the camel [AsyncProcessor API](http://camel.apache.org/asynchronous-processing.html) to call the callback done once you processing the message from BlockingQueue.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out to AsyncProcessor API. Say, if my processing is completed, then who do I send the acknowledgement explicitly in this case? Or otherwise, how would the acknowledgement work if I am not sending it explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

I bumped into the same issue.

The Camel RabbitMQConsumer.RabbitConsumer implementation does

```
consumer.getProcessor().process(exchange);

long deliveryTag = envelope.getDeliveryTag();
if (!consumer.endpoint.isAutoAck()) {
  log.trace("Acknowledging receipt [delivery_tag={}]", deliveryTag);
  channel.basicAck(deliveryTag, false);
}
```

So it's just expecting a synchronous processor. 
If you bind this to a seda route for instance, the process method returns immediately and you're pretty much back to the autoAck situation.

My understanding is that we need to make our own RabbitMQ component to do something like

```
consumer.getAsyncProcessor().process(exchange, new AsynCallback() {
  public void done(doneSync) {
    if (!consumer.endpoint.isAutoAck()) {
      long deliveryTag = envelope.getDeliveryTag();
      log.trace("Acknowledging receipt [delivery_tag={}]", deliveryTag);
      channel.basicAck(deliveryTag, false);
    }
  }
});
```

Even then, the semantics of the "doneSync" parameter is not clear to me. I think it's merely a marker to identify whether we're dealing with a real async processor or a synchronous processor that was automatically wrapped into an async one.

Maybe someone can validate or invalidate this solution?

Is there a lighter/faster/stronger alternative?

Or could this be suggested as the default implementation for the RabbitMQConsumer?

Comment: I just checked the implem in the new 2.14.x release.
It's better at handling errors and sending a basicReject back to Rabbit, but it still looks synchronous to me :(

Comment: I did a work around by acknowledging messages in batch instead of acknowledging every message separately.

Comment: @arry could you please share the solution