# RabbitMQ and Camel 2.20 Auto Acknowledges even when autoAck=false

Tags: java, rabbitmq, apache-camel

I am new to Camel and RabbitMQ and is writing a simple consumer with this route below

```
  from("rabbitmq://127.0.0.1?username=admin&password=admin&queue=TestQueue&routingKey=TestQueue&exchangeName=''&autoAck=false&autoDelete=false").delay(3000).bean(exceptionBean,"throwGenericException").log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Receiving from the Queue: ${id}");
```

The Bean has no code but simply throws an exception. My issue is that even after throwing an Exception from bean, the message gets auto acknowledged at the queue.

1. What am i missing in this case ?. what is the best way to handle the
   failure?.

Why is camel auto acknowledging it at the end of the route?.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Try with Camel 2.20.2

Comment: Perhaps this is still relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24804448/camel-raabitmq-acknowledgement

Comment: Am allready on <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-rabbitmq -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
   <artifactId>camel-rabbitmq</artifactId>
   <version>2.20.2</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Hi, Did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link

https://gist.github.com/mgyongyosi/fa71a52da65a9dd3cddd537fb4feca66

The Route needs to have setFaultBody set as true inorder to not auto acknowledge. Try the above sample and it will give you an idea.

Regards
Aravind

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your exception is because the parameter exchangeName not exist,

Try call your RabbitMQ like this:

```
from("rabbitmq:{{RABBITMQ_ADDRESS}}/{{RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE}}?routingKey={{RABBITMQ_QUEUE_IN_ROUTING_KEY}}&username={{RABBITMQ_USERNAME}}&password={{RABBITMQ_PSWD}}&autoDelete=false&queue={{RABBITMQ_QUEUE_IN}}")
```